# Get Top Few Rows which satifies the Condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to get First Two Rows which are having C = '1',
I'm ordering the query by TimeStamp Descending, I dont want 
the Last row to be Fetched by query

```
    A      B  C   TimeStamp
 ------------------------------------
  foo    one  1   20180405153936
  foo    two  1   20180405153936
  foo    two  2   20180405115417
  foo    one  2   20180405115053
  foo  three  1   20180405113923
```

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: No i have not able to figure it out @Tim

Comment: I don't Understand why people are down voting, You can Comment what is wrong the question. You should not discourage the new comers. Please

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but it probably happened because you showed zero effort.

Comment: As I'm Not so good in SQL, I'm unable to figure it out. I'll Learn definitely in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ROWNUM` construct, but keep in mind that unless you wrap the ordering select, `ROWNUM` will bring back the rows in whatever order they were added to the table.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM 
         yourTable
     WHERE C = 1 
     ORDER BY "TimeStamp" DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 2
```

**EDIT**

Given the added information, the following will probably work better than using a `ROWNUM`.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    yourTable
WHERE 
    C = 1 AND 
    "TimeStamp" > (
        SELECT MIN("TimeStamp") FROM yourTable WHERE C = 1
    ) 
ORDER BY "TimeStamp" DESC
```

Comment: The thing is i'll be not knowing how many rows at the top which are satisfying the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROWNUM`

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM 
     Table1 
 WHERE C=1
 ORDER BY "TimeStamp" DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE C=1)-1
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/08ed98/11

Comment: Actually Its not fixed to two rows, it may also be more at the Top

Comment: so you in place of 2 you can write any number

Comment: That is not possible, I'll be not knowing how many rows at the Top, Its dynamically Generating

Comment: This won't work. Try inserting the third row first, and see what result you get.

Comment: Check the answer now i edited my answer @ViKu

Comment: It's Working Fine Thanks @Jai Shankar

Comment: Welcome!! @ViKu